# Trying to edit "React Native init" file structure

Tags: javascript, android, compilation, react-native

I have been trying to get my head around React Native as I recently took the decision to switch to it from Cordova.

I have been trying to understand how container and component files should be properly structured inside src in order to correctly build.

To this end I have been attempting to run the initial index.android.js code out of a new file "app.js" which I have created in a folder I called js found in the original /src/main folder.

This is the index file code

```
/*Both index files index.ios.js and index.android.js MUST be indentical*/
var React= require('react-native');
var { AppRegistry } = React;
var App = require('./android/app/src/main/js/app.js')
AppRegistry.registerComponent('LearnD', () => LearnD);
```

And the app.js file can be found at this [gist here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7b3c9d7924f601c5d4ef1b54ab8a60fc).

I have been then receiving the following error:
[image: Error]

Any help will be more than appreciated.
Thanks in advance,
Jake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical setup for a React Native application looks something like:

```
└── YourApp
    ├── android           # Native Android files, no .js here
    ├── index.android.js  # Android entry point, must exist
    ├── index.ios.js      # iOS entry point, must exist
    ├── ios               # Native iOS files, no .js here
    └── src               # All your .js sources
        ├── components    # All your .js sources
        └── main.js       # Your shared entry point
```

Your `src/main.js` can then export a single, shared entry point component for both platforms and uses other components inside the `src/` directory:

```
// src/main.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import OtherComponent from './components/other-component.js'

// note export default
export default class Main extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <OtherComponent />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

And your `index.ios.js` and `index.android.js` components can import and register the main component as the application root component:

```
// index.ios.js and index.android.js
// both must exist, but they can be identical
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import Main from './src/main';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('YourApp', () => Main);
```

Within the `src` directory, you can then structure your app code in any way you best see fit, e.g. `src/components` and `src/containers` - entirely up to you!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer @jevakallio .
Intensely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your file is trying to export `App` on line 48, which does not exist. You already have `export default class LearnD` on line 10, so omit line 48 and that should help